# .properties file not getting created in a java dynamic web application

Tags: java, properties

I am Developing a java Web application in which i want to use properties class for storing username and password ans store those in XYZ.properties files. when i execute the code, the XYZ.properties file is not getting created. i want to add username and password to this properties file for every user registration. So I am calling the method to create the properties file from a Servlet.

**Code snippet below**

```
public  String insertUser(String uname,String password, Properties UserDetails) throws NullPointerException,IOException,FileNotFoundException
    {

        UserDetails.setProperty(uname, password);

        try {
            File file = new File("XYZ.properties");
            FileOutputStream  fw=new FileOutputStream (file);
            UserDetails.store(fw, "my:op");
```

Comment: is there anything else in `try` block?? and are u getting any exception?

Comment: You're using a relative path. Are you sure it stored the file into the directory you're looking at?

Comment: There is nothing else in the tr  bloc and checked that now exception s being thrown....I checked each and every folder in the application i did not find any file with the name i specified...